# How would I lock a screen in landscape mode in a Sencha Touch web app

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

My ST app is not implemented using the Native wrapper rather it is distributed via the browser. Is it still possible to lock a screen into landscape mode even if the device has been rotated?
If so how is this achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. You can just display a message to users on `orientationchange` event in order to let them know that they should not view your app in portrait mode.